# No hook for new order on woocommerce in a plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I tried about 5 hooks to get the order hook for completed and the function doesn't run at all but woocommerce_add_to_cart for example is working!

```
1. woocommerce_order_status_changed
```

`2. woocommerce_new_order`

I just make the alert to know if the function runs but the fucntion is quite large and I make order **manullay** as a test before deploying the plugin in this function in the plugin in `index.php`

```
    function SP_order_token($order_id)
    {
    
    
    ?>
        <script>
            alert("hello");
            alert('<?php echo $order_id; ?>');
        </script>
        <?php
        echo "hello";
    
        global $woocommerce, $post;
  
      
        echo $order_id;
    
        $order =    wc_get_order($order_id);
    
        $order_data = $order->get_data(); // The Order data
    
        var_dump($order_data);
     }
// the final hook is when an order successfully paid
        add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'SP_order_token',10,1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach for debugging php is wrong. You can't alert or do JS things on the server side. Also, `var_dump` and `echo` will work but you don't know where they gonna echo or dump the output.

The correct way for php debugging will be to write your output in external files or in error logs. but I prefer writing in files on the root of wordpress.

Here is the code snippet that you can use:

```php
function sp_order_token( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order_data = $order->get_data();

    /**
     * We're using file_put_contents to create a debug.txt file in the root of wordpress where your wp-config.php exists.
     * 
     * we're also passing true in print_r so that print_r returns the output instead of printing it during code execution.
     * 
     * ABSPATH is a constant of wordpress root defined by core WordPress.
     */
    file_put_contents( ABSPATH . 'debug.txt', print_r($order_data, true ) );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'sp_order_token', 10, 1 );
```

Once your action will run in wordpress root you'll find `debug.txt` with your expected output.

Comment: Thanks it works this way if you just may change the hook to `add_action('woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta', 'SP_order_token', 10, 1);` 
because when orders created from the WC Admin the hook firing with`woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta`

Comment: May I ask if I want to get the attributes of a product that the customer select when he buys, for example size and color that he selected, I think it's simple that I don't want to post new question for but I can't find something realted after buying.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace with this and check again.

```
function woo_order_status_change_custom_check($order_id) {

    ?>
    <script>
        alert("hello");
        alert('<?php echo $order_id; ?>');
    </script>
    <?php
    
    // echo "hello";

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $orderstatus = $order->status;

    var_dump($orderstatus);

}

add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'woo_order_status_change_custom_check', 10, 1);
```

Comment: the function doesn't even run! no idea why can't hook.

Comment: your previous action hook called "SP_order_token" this function but you did not call this function

Comment: Oh sorry it's a typo but both functions has the same code alert for testing.

Comment: `wc-admin_import_orders Complete 
0 => 1834
wc-admin-data Non-repeating 2022-09-20 13:07:47 +0000
(2 minutes 27 seconds ago) 
2022-09-20 13:07:42 +0000
action created
2022-09-20 13:08:46 +0000
action started via WP Cron
2022-09-20 13:08:46 +0000
action complete via WP Cron`

Comment: this's the schedule actions there's action already but without execuation.

Comment: By the way, I change the status or creating new order manally from WC Orders, I think it's doesn't differ right?